# What is the difference between include and include_once with and without round brackets

Tags: php

i recently find out that there are more types of `include()` in php
My question is what is the diference between the folowing instructions:

```
include_once 'file.txt';
include 'file.txt';

include ('file.txt');
include_once ('file.txt');
```

If `file.txt` is not created what is the error message I get?

Comment: `include_once` does just what it says it does. It includes the page once. If you call it later with `include_once`, it will not include it because it's already been included. The other will include as many times it's called.

Comment: but there are 2 tipes of it one with () and one without , what is the diference?

Comment: No difference. Preference of syntax (to my understanding anyway. I only use brackets).

Comment: But i rember my teacher said some will generate an "fatal error" if the file.txt is not created while  others will not.

Comment: The reason you would `include_once` is for things like functions. If you call a page twice that contains the defining of a function, it will give you a fatal error.

Comment: @StemFlorin Your teacher is talking about `require`, not `include`.

Comment: thank you , now i understant now . :)

Comment: @StemFlorin The PHP reference manual covers this in considerable detail [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), which should be your first stop with a question like this rather than asking us to regurgitate it for you.

Comment: i am sorry , i will check the manul from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parentheses around the filename make no difference. `include` is a language construct, not a function, so it doesn't require parenthese around its arguments. So they're equivalent, just like:

```
echo "foo";
echo ("foo");
```

So there are just two forms: `include` and `include_once`. The difference between them is what happens if you try to include the same file multiple times in the same script. `include` will include it each time, `include_once` will only do it the first time, and ignore all the repeats.

You generally use `include` if the file performs some action, such as echoing HTML or setting variables. `include_once` is used for files that define functions and classes, because these will get an error if you try to redefine them.

If the file doesn't exist, you'll get warnings like this:

> Warning: include(file.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /path/to/your/script.php on line 4
>       Warning: include(): Failed opening 'file.txt' for inclusion (include_path='.:') in /path/to/your/script.php on line 4

The warning is the same for `include` and `include_once`.

There's also `require` and `require_once`. They're just like `include` and `include_once`, but instead of printing a warning if the file doesn't exist, it prints an error and stops the script.

Comment: I wonder which part of my answer wasn't explained in your textbook or the documentation at php.net?

Comment: i couldnt find the side by side comparison.

Comment: and then i checked the manul on php. net , and found it [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)....This is kinda awkward.I am sorry.